# Passing variable from mulitple functions to another function in C

Tags: c, function

Basically I need to pass the ret variable from the functions checkPOS, checkPOS1, checkPOS2 to the result() function, if the sum of the 3 ret variables equals to zero, user's access is granted, in case it is 1+, the access is denied. How can I pass the 3 variables to the result function?

```
 void checkPOS2(struct Node* n, int pos, int alg, int input) {
    
        int ret3;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++) {
            n = n->next;
        }
    
        
    
        if (input == n->data[alg]) {
            printf("Numero certo (");
            printf("%d", n->data[0]);
            printf("%d", n->data[1]);
            printf("%d)", n->data[2]);
            ret3 = 0;
            return ret3;
        }
        else {
            printf("Numero errado (");
            printf("%d", n->data[0]);
            printf("%d", n->data[1]);
            printf("%d)", n->data[2]);
            ret3 = 1;
            return ret3;
        }
    
    
    }
    
    void result() {
      
        
        if ((ret3) == 0) { printf("Acesso Permitido!"); }
        else { printf("Acesso Negado!"); }
    
        printf("%d", ret3);
        
    
    }
```

Comment: Didn't your compiler raise an error when you try to return a value? That is already  the hint: You must define your functions to have a non-void return type and then in the caller you can assign the return value to a variable. You can do that for all 3 functions and then pass the value(s) to `result` function where you need to define a parameter for it). I suggest you revisit the chapter about function definitions (parameters, return type) in your learning material.

Comment: They must be passed as an argument to result. `void result(int ret1, int ret2, int ret3);` and do the test in the result function.

Comment: Please raise the warning level of your compiler to the maximum and correct anything it reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to take parameter as well.

```
void result(int r) 
{
        if ((r) == 0) { printf("Acesso Permitido!"); }
        else { printf("Acesso Negado!"); }
    
        printf("%d", r);
}
```

and before you call it:

```
int res = checkPOSx(....);
result(res);
```

or

```
result(checkPOSx(....));
```

Comment: You might add that this will not work with these signatures: `void checkPOS2(...`